# How to prove something is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Hi I have this question from my homework sheet:

> "Let $Π$ be a plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ passing through the origin, and parallel to some vectors $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then the set $V$, of position vectors of points of $Π$, is given by $V=\{μa+νb: μ,ν\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Prove that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$."

I think I need to prove that:

I) The zero vector is in $V$.

II) Vector addition is closed.

III) Scalar multiplication is closed.

For I) could I just let $μ$ and $ν$ be zero so it passes so the zero vector is in $V$.

For II) I think I'd start with two arbitrary vectors say $x$ and $y$ but I'm not sure where to substitute them in.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $x, y ∈ V$ you may much rather *expand* them as $x = μ_xa + ν_xb$ and $y = μ_ya + ν_yb$ for some $μ_x, ν_x, μ_y, ν_y ∈ ℝ$.

Answer (score 3):

So you need to show that

(i) $0$ can be written as $\mu a + \nu b$ for some choice of $\mu,\nu$

(ii) $(\mu_1 a + \nu_1 b) + (\mu_2 a + \nu_2 b)$ can be written as $\mu a + \nu b$ for some choice of $\mu,\nu$

(iii) $\lambda(\mu_1 a + \nu_1 b)$ can be written as $\mu a + \nu b$ for some choice of $\mu,\nu$

**Hints:** (Mouse over each to reveal)

For (i):

> Take $\mu = 0$ and $\nu=0$

For (ii):

> Take $\mu=\mu_1+\mu_2$ and $\nu=\nu_1 + \nu_2$

For (iii):

> Take $\mu = \lambda\mu_1$ and $\nu = \lambda\nu_1$

Answer (score 1):

Two vectors of $\Pi$ are of the form $\lambda a+\mu b$ and $\lambda'a+\mu'b$. Just add them.

Comment: Here, vectors are in $V$. The set $Π$ contains points of a plane.